# How to set a module to Null in python

Tags: python, module, nonetype

1. I am importing a module as a param here

   - In [9]: import config.api.users_parameter as param
2. Now param is a module and i am fetching the data from the variables under param like below 
   In [10]: type(param)
   Out[10]: module

Ex: param.userList

3. During the script run i am assigning multiple variables also to this param module
4. When the suite is complete i need to empty the variables in param, so that next suite will import this module again.
5. Now the same module is getting over written in each suites which is causing failure.
6. How to set the variables under the param as None or remove all the variables under the param module

Comment: try doing `del config` this will delete the variable.

Comment: add a `reset()` method to your module that resets your variables to initial values - it looks as if you just use a module as value-store - why not simply use a dictionary instead?